# How can I make a `View` fill a `RelativeLayout`?

Tags: android, layout, view, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with some stuff in it, and I want a background view to fill the whole thing. This is what I would expect to work:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="1px"
                android:background="#fafafa" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_blank_profile" />

        .... and so on.
```

That doesn't work. It fills the width but the height gets set to zero. However, if I change `layout_alignParentBottom` to `layout_alignBottom="@+id/im"` then it *does* work (sort of; that's not a satisfactory solution but at least it isn't 0 height any more).

What's going on? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `layout_height` property of you relative layout to `match_parent`

And what happens if you remove all the `alignParent` properties from the view and just use `match_parent` for the width and the height of the view?

Rolf

**Final Edit?:**

Small example, something like this?
Using a container? When the content of the inner RelativeLayout grows the View will just stretch with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="1px"
            android:background="#fafafa" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_blank_profile" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The type of the `layout_height` of the `RelativeLayout` won't affect any of its children. I mean it is already a non-zero height so `match_parent` in the children *should* fill it. And sadly I already tried your second suggestion. No joy.

Comment: Re your edit: Yes that is what my code currently looks like, and is the best I have, but it is not the solution I am looking for. If you add other views to the `RelativeLayout` so that it becomes bigger, the background `View` will no longer fill it.

Comment: Edited my post, now i'm using a container to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Yeah I mean... of course I could just use a `FrameLayout` to contain the background view and another `RelativeLayout` like you have (basically; there's no need to use two `RelativeLayout`s!). But that seems like overkill to get something that seems like it should work without another layout.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the relative layout from

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Because you are wrapping the height of the parent to the child, and the child to match the parent, it will come up 0.

if you are wanting to have other things above/below the relative layout, then use android weights.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"  <!-- or 0dip -->
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000" >
```

Comment: That's not how `match_parent` works. And also I don't want my `RelativeLayout` to fill its parent or be expandable.

Comment: @Timmmm So doing either of these doesnt make it visible?

Comment: No. In fact setting `layout_height="match_parent"` in a vertical `LinearLayout` (which it is in) has no effect. I think the `LinearLayout` ignores that because it would make no sense.

Comment: as its in a linear layout, your best off using weights as I suggested. Using match_parent in a linear layout is perfectly acceptable, just not in this scenario.

Comment: I don't follow. Using `layout_weight="0"` will expand the view, which I don't want. And I should have said `match_parent` has no effect and makes no sense in the orientation direction of a `LinearLayout`, e.g. `layout_height="match_parent"` inside a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"` which is what I have. Clearly you can use it in the other direction!